# Books for the outdoors

Tags: books

I'm looking for a book that teaches serious mountain skills like **Freedom of the Hills** minus the snow but all that I could find in the internet so far are in the context of North America and/or is all about backpacking/thru hiking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'serious mountain skills'? Freedom of the Hills is pretty comprehensive as far as basic introductions go, and includes rock climbing in addition to ice climbing and snow/glacier travel. Could you be more specific as to what you're looking to learn?

Comment: Basically, is there a book that is like Freedom of the Hills minus the snow part? Mountaineering without ice, if that makes sense (because we don't have ice). I know, why not just buy the book and not read the ice part. I'm just asking, maybe there is something that compares.

Comment: So are you looking for an introduction to rock climbing?

Comment: I'm wondering what more you would expect to get out of Freedom of the Hills if you were to take the sections about snow out? Freedom of the Hills has been THE resource for mountaineers for a hundred years. You are not going to find a better book. Just skip the parts about snow if you aren't interested.

Comment: @PatrickN but Freedom of the Hills contains more than just ice/rock climbing, right? It has sections on navigation, survival, rescue, training, equipment, ropemanship, etc. I was hoping maybe there is a book that contains all that good stuff minus the discussion about ice related things.

Comment: I don't understand the reluctance to have the snow/ice information even if you have no plans to ever set foot on snow or ice.   Do you plan to carry the book and the snow/ice parts make the book too heavy?  If so, why not rip out the pages that deal with snow and ice, or are they too interspersed in the book?

Answer (score 3):

I'm from the UK and our Mountain Leader Training association has a series of [5 books](http://www.mountain-training.org/publications)

1. Hillwalking
2. Rock Climbing
3. Winter Skills
4. Navigation in the Mountains
5. International Mountain Trekking

I own #1 and #4 and can recommend them (you can leave out #3). They are quite a bit geared towards the UK (e.g. detailed discussion of our OS maps) but the principles in them should be applicable anywhere.

Other ones maybe worth a look are the [cicerone](http://www.cicerone.co.uk/product/index.cfm/menu/50/cid/74/catalogue/techniques) series.